# Read multiple parquet files with selected columns into one Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I am trying to read multiple parquet files with selected columns into one Pandas dataframe. This means that the parquet files don't share all the columns. I tried to add a `filter()` argument into the `pd.read_parquet()` but it seems that it doesn't work in the multiple file reading. How can I make this work?

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

data_dir = Path('dir/to/parquet/files')
full_df = pd.concat(
    pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)
    for parquet_file in data_dir.glob('*.parquet')
)


full_df = pd.concat(
    pd.read_parquet(parquet_file, filters=[('name', 'address', 'email')])
    for parquet_file in data_dir.glob('*.parquet')
)
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `columns` instead of `filters`?  `columns` is for extracting specific columns and `filters` is to filter data with conditions (ie: `[('name', '>', 'Mary')]`).  Also, for me passing directory path to `read_parquet` read all files without for loop.  I am using pandas==1.2.4.

Answer (score 4):

Reading from multiple files is well supported.  However, if your schemas are different then it is a bit trickier.  Pyarrow currently defaults to using the schema of the first file it finds in a dataset.  This is to avoid the up-front cost of inspecting the schema of every file in a large dataset.

Arrow-C++ has [the capability](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/dataset.html?highlight=inspectoptions#_CPPv4N5arrow7dataset14InspectOptionsE) to override this and scan every file but this is not yet exposed in pyarrow.  However, if you know the unified schema ahead of time you can supply it and you will get the behavior you want.  You will need to use the datasets module directly to do this as specifying a schema is not part of `pyarrow.parquet.read_table` (which is what is called by `pandas.read_parquet`).

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

import tempfile

tab1 = pa.Table.from_pydict({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
tab2 = pa.Table.from_pydict({'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c': [True, False, True]})

unified_schema = pa.unify_schemas([tab1.schema, tab2.schema])

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dataset_dir:

    pq.write_table(tab1, f'{dataset_dir}/one.parquet')
    pq.write_table(tab2, f'{dataset_dir}/two.parquet')

    print('Basic read of directory will use schema from first file')
    print(pd.read_parquet(dataset_dir))

    print()
    print('You can specify the unified schema if you know it')
    dataset = ds.dataset(dataset_dir, schema=unified_schema)
    print(dataset.to_table().to_pandas())

    print()
    print('The columns option will limit which columns are returned from read_parquet')
    print(pd.read_parquet(dataset_dir, columns=['b']))

    print()
    print('The columns option can be used when specifying a schema as well')
    dataset = ds.dataset(dataset_dir, schema=unified_schema)
    print(dataset.to_table(columns=['b', 'c']).to_pandas())
```

If you don't know the unified schema ahead of time you can create it by inspecting all the files yourself:

```
# You could also use glob here or whatever tool you want to
# get the list of files in your dataset
dataset = ds.dataset(dataset_dir)
schemas = [pq.read_schema(dataset_file) for dataset_file in dataset.files]
print(pa.unify_schemas(schemas))
```

Since this might be expensive (especially if working with a remote filesystem) you may want to save off the unified schema in its own file (saving a parquet file or Arrow IPC file with 0 batches is usually sufficient) instead of recalculating it every time.