# Infer the correct schema in case of partitioned parquet in pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, schema, parquet, pyarrow

I have a big partitioned parquet that I need to access either loading it all or filtering it. I am not able to load the entire file because of this error `ArrowNotImplementedError: Unsupported cast from string to null using function cast_null`. From [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70566660/parquet-with-null-columns-on-pyarrow) it turns out to be a problem linked to the first file used to infer the overall schema. If I generate a *unifiedSchema* and use it to load the entire dataframe I have no problem at all, but when I apply a filter passing the schema the following error pops up:
`ArrowInvalid: No match for FieldRef.Name(MARKET_TAG) in PRODUCT_TAG: string`

```py
df = pd.read_parquet("data/reduced.parquet",filters=[("MARKET_TAG","=",3)],schema=unifiedSchema)
```

There is a way to solve this?

I was thinking to solve the problem directly storing the correct schema with **pq.write_to_dataset** but I use to work on several datasets with a single "MARKET_TAG" and to store the parquets at the end using *partition_cols* in the same folder. In this case, the table schema could be "wrong" compared with the other, not solving my issue.